# How to display half year based on year selection and disable half year for future years Angular 8

Tags: javascript, jquery, node.js, angular, angular8

I have year and half year dropdown in UI,Based on selected year i want to change half year dropdown
Can anyone help me to implement below logic to achieve my expected output

**For ex -** If user selected 2021 or 2022 or 2023 in the dropdown than it will display
option1 H1(Jan-June), option2 H2(July-Dec) both bcz till 2023 all years are completed.

And for future years or for every new year for ex 2024 or 2025, options H1(Jan-June) only enables when july month start
and option2 H2(July-Dec) only enables when January of the new year starts.

**Expected output**

```
2022 Display option1 H1(Jan-June) and  option2 H2(July-Dec)
2023 Display option1 H1(Jan-June) and  option2 H2(July-Dec)
2024 Enable option1 H1(Jan-June) When July month starts and option2 H2(July-Dec) enables when January of 2025 starts
like wise....
```

**Below is my code for dropdown and half year slicer**

```
<mat-select>
                        <mat-option *ngFor="let year of years" [value]="year">
                            {{year}}
                        </mat-option>
                    </mat-select>

                     <mat-select class="lineDet subfamilySelect lossSubMatCls" placeholder="Select half Year">
                        <mat-option *ngFor="let type of halfYearlyOptions" [value]="type"> {{type}}
                        </mat-option>
                    </mat-select>

                **Component**

years: number[] = [];
halfYearlyOptions = ['H1 Jan-June', 'H2 July-Dec'];
ngOnInit(){
    for (let date = new Date(2020, 6, 1); date < now; date = new Date(date.setFullYear(date.getFullYear() + 1))) {
        this.years.push(date.getFullYear());
      }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the `selectionChange` to listen for the latest value, then apply the logic to filter the dropdown based on the conditions mentioned!

Code explanation on comments in the code!

```
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { bootstrapApplication } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { MatSelectModule } from '@angular/material/select';
import 'zone.js';
import { provideAnimations } from '@angular/platform-browser/animations';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  standalone: true,
  imports: [CommonModule, MatSelectModule],
  template: `
    <mat-select (selectionChange)="selectionChange($event)">
        <mat-option *ngFor="let year of years" [value]="year">
            {{year}}
        </mat-option>
    </mat-select>

      <mat-select class="lineDet subfamilySelect lossSubMatCls" placeholder="Select half Year">
        <mat-option *ngFor="let type of halfYearlyOptions" [value]="type"> {{type}}
        </mat-option>
    </mat-select>
  `,
})
export class App {
  years: number[] = [];
  // take a backup of the original array, since we need to refernce these values conditionally
  halfYearlyOptionsOriginal: Array<string> = ['H1 Jan-June', 'H2 July-Dec'];
  // use this array to conditionally add values based on logic
  halfYearlyOptions: Array<string> = [];
  ngOnInit() {
    const now = new Date();
    for (
      // I changed this to show 2024, you can revert it if needed
      let date = new Date(2020, 0, 1);
      date < now;
      date = new Date(date.setFullYear(date.getFullYear() + 1))
    ) {
      console.log(date);
      this.years.push(date.getFullYear());
    }
  }

  selectionChange(year: any) {
    // get the year from the event coming from mat select
    const yearInput = year && year.value;
    // get the todays date
    const currentTime = new Date();
    // get todays year
    var nowYear = currentTime.getFullYear();
    // get todays month, since zero index add 1
    var nowMonth = currentTime.getMonth() + 1;
    // your logic goes here, we need to check month is not before 7 and current year
    if (yearInput === nowYear && nowMonth <= 6) {
      // assign no items
      this.halfYearlyOptions = [];
      // your logic goes here, we need to check month is after 6 and current year
    } else if (yearInput === nowYear && nowMonth > 6) {
      // assign only the first item
      this.halfYearlyOptions = [this.halfYearlyOptionsOriginal[0]];
    } else {
      // all other scenarios assign all items!
      this.halfYearlyOptions = [...this.halfYearlyOptionsOriginal];
    }
  }
}

bootstrapApplication(App, {
  providers: [provideAnimations()],
});
```

[stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/stackblitz-starters-4lh16x?description=An%20angular-cli%20project%20based%20on%20@angular/animations,%20@angular/common,%20@angular/compiler,%20@angular/core,%20@angular/forms,%20@angular/platform-browser,%20@angular/platform-browser-dynamic,%20@angular/router,%20core-js,%20rxjs,%20tslib%20and%20zone.js&file=src%2Fmain.ts,src%2Fglobal_styles.css&title=Angular%20Starter)